# Simulating window functions in Firebird

Tags: firebird

Is there anyone can help me with my query.

here is my table.

[image]

when I run my query. result illustrated below.

[image]

TOTAL_BINS_PER_SITE field is the sum of bin count group by SITE. Here is my query

```
  SELECT
    X.SITE,
    X.STATUS,
    X.TOTAL_BINS_PER_BIN,
    (SELECT SUM(BIN_COUNT) FROM TS_BINS_PER_SITE WHERE ID = X.ID) AS TOTAL_BINS_PER_SITE
FROM
    (SELECT ID, SUM(BIN_COUNT) AS TOTAL_BINS_PER_BIN, SITE AS SITE, STATUS AS STATUS
    FROM TS_BINS_PER_SITE
    WHERE STATUS = 'P'
    AND ID = (
       SELECT A.ID
       FROM TS_REC_DATA A
       JOIN TS_MAIN_REC B
       ON A.REC_ID = B.ID
       WHERE B.LOT_ID = 'QYYZCA004K'
       AND B.TESTER_ID = 'LTXMXSPC035'
       AND A.DATEMODIFIED = '5/30/2014 10:01:05')
       GROUP BY SITE, STATUS, ID
) X
```

it is working but the problem is TOTAL_BINS_PER_SITE will sum all the bin count, what I expected is it will sum the BIN_COUNT group by site. example is the Site 1, the TOTAL_BINS_PER_SITE suppose to be 5 only because bin_count 4 + bin_count 1 in SITE 1.
I know that my query in 5th line is missing "GROUP BY SITE", but when I added it the 5th line, error says "multiple rows in singleton select". Anyone can help me out of here? Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your subquery in the select has the condition `WHERE ID = X.ID`, instead you should use `WHERE SITE = X.SITE` (or maybe `WHERE SITE = X.SITE AND ID = X.ID`) to only get the items for that site in the summation.

In the Firebird 3 this can be simplified using [window functions](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs), for example by using

```
SUM(TOTAL_BINS_PER_BIN) OVER (GROUP BY X.SITE) AS TOTAL_BINS_PER_SITE
```

instead of the subquery in your select.